Simulating data removal and determining whether it has significant impact on a specific metric
Example scenario: I have a class of 2000 students. My class is pass/fail. On average, the pass rate of my class is 85%. I want to simulate what would happen to the overall pass rate if I removed 100 non-passing students, and whether that difference is statistically significant. Note: if a student is removed from the class, they are not replaced with a new student.
I'm tempted to just simulate this by removing those students from my overall grade calculation and determine a new pass-rate, but it feels like there is a more rigorous way to approach this.

I may be missing the whole point of the question, but the answer seems obvious. You have 1700 pass students, and 300 fail ones; after removal of exclusively non-passing students, you have 1700 pass students and 200 fail ones. Stick the values in a 2x2 contingency matrix, use Fisher-exact or $\chi^2$, and see the result (btw, yes, it is "very significant"). Am I missing something in the problem?
